# OSB Response message is not coming?

Tags: osb

When i deploy the composite in the OSB Console and Execute with some payload in the Response section it is showing The invocation resulted in an error: Not Found.
What might be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Error you are seeing basically means you got http 404 not found response from server you where calling. Double check if your BusinessService endpoint URI is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether do you have replace action in your flow and that should be replaced with body, so t can overwrite body and shown it in Response